# Android store multiple notification ID and allow more than 1 notification showing at same time

Tags: android, notifications

I'm using a AsyncTask that downloads an apk file and then install it at post execute method.

Pre Execute
{

```
Get a notification variable from shared preference and adds +1 to it
Create a new notification based on this variable
```

}

Do In Background
{

```
 Update this notification based on its ID -1 (to refer to initial notification ID)
```

}

Post Execute
{

```
Update this notification based on its ID -1 (to refer to initial notification ID)
```

}

At the same time when this thread is running (example downloading a very large file over network) I would allow user to start another download. In this case I want to show 2 notifications instead of reusing the same notification ID. What is the best way to have 2 unique notification ID that does not conflict when i'm referring its Notification ID in Do In Background and Post Execute thread? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution after taking a nap to rest. Must have been too tired to figure it out

I've placed a local variable `private int notification_ID` inside each `AsyncTask`
After creating the notification, insert into shared preference (Notification_ID + 1)
Do In Background and Post Execute still uses this private variable when updating this notification

When a new `AsyncTask` thread is started, it will first read from shared preference which will be a new value (assuming first was 0, second would be 0+1 = 1) Then when its Do In Background and Post Execute try to access its `notification_ID` it will be accessing its own private variable with the value 1 hence will not conflict with first or subsequent notifications